# Don't Starve Together - Alone mode vs Don't Starve

Tags: dont-starve, dont-starve-together

When you try playing Don't Starve Together for the first time, the game recommends you to play Alone mode.

Does Don't Starve Together - Alone mode make the original Don't Starve obsolete, or does the original Don't Starve have unique content in it's own right compared to Don't Starve Together - Alone mode?

Comment: If your asking what to get on a limited budget, consider you will probably only play one version most of the time. Do you prefer to play alone or with friends? Also Ship Wrecked is only available for DS (at the moment). If you can get both, it's worth it in my opinion. Both have unique content. Still you will  have way more time on one version then the other.

Comment: @coteyr, fair comment. I have both game but I have not played either. Wanted to suggest DST to a friend for our next play session and in order to prepare for it started it up. And then it told me that I should first play alone before inviting a friend. So I was wondering which game should I play alone first, the original or DTS alone mode. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I would add that last comment to your question. It' makes a HUGE difference in a recommendation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The two versions of the game are balanced differently in terms of difficulty.

As you can read in [this discussion](http://steamcommunity.com/app/322330/discussions/0/619574421433381738/) on the Steam Community, one of the devs says exactly that: you can play Don't Starve Together as a solo game, to start to grasp the mechanics, but as you start to progress you'll find harder content than the "base" version. Some of the challenges that Together makes you face are not meant to be tackled by yourself. Take for example the [Ewecus](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Ewecus): its spit can trap you for a few seconds and, while it could be overcome by having a friendly Pigman, having another player come to your aid makes the fight significantly easier.

In addition, at the moment of this writing, Together features the content of the base game and Reign of Giants, but not the Shipwrecked content.

Many things were modified or rebalanced too, due to the intrinsic power of some of the characters, and special encounters and events have been added to adapt to the multiplayer aspect. You can read the whole list of differences on the [wiki page](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Don%27t_Starve_Together).

Comment: Is it known how many players is DST balanced for? You are saying that it's not meant to be beaten solo. Is it meant to be beaten with 2 people? 4? More than that? Thanks!

Comment: @zespri More than one. A couple of experienced players can overcome even the fiercest foes if they know what they're doing. The problem with playing alone is in monsters like the Ewecus, that have mechanics that can easily be overcome with another player, but are very hard when faced alone.

Comment: They are different takes on the same game. Aside from specific content, DST is balanced for more then one player, including some pretty big things like Tell-Tell Hearts and changing abilities to be more useful (or less damaging) in a group setting.

Answer (score 7):

Well...

Don't Starve has a couple small unique things, since they couldn't be reworked for multiplayer. Don't Starve Together has significantly more stuff.

Don's Starve has a few exclusive mods.

Don't Starve Together has skins, but some mechanics that were reworked require more players -- All bosses have 2x the HP they had in Don't Starve, except for the Dragonfly which has 10x the amount of health it normally does.

All-in-all, I recommend getting both! Don't Starve has Shipwrecked and Don't Starve Together is just awesome!

Answer (score 5):

Based on you comments I would recommend playing Don't Starve Together Alone, first.

DST has unique content and game mechanics not available in DS. If your trying to warm up to play with a friend then best to warm up with all the same mechanics.

You will find that playing DST alone is more challenging then if you were to play DS. However, you will find that if you play DS then try to transition that knowladge to DST, there will be areas that just seem "off" because of mechanic differences.

A great example is looking at the map. In DS, when you look at the map the game pauses. You can spend a long time looking at the map to try to figure out the place you want to go "today". In DST the game does not pause to look at the map. If you spend too much time trying to figure out where to go you will run out of day time. This small change can be a hard habit to break when transitioning to DST.